# Confirm APK identity with keystore

Tags: android, authentication, key, keystore

I am building an Android application that communicates with an online webservice. I plan on releasing the application's source code on GitHub. For my production version, which will utilize my personal webservice I want to allow only my digitally signed apk to connect.

Is is possible to request the APK's keystore and confirm the username/password from that keystore?

If this is not possible how else can I produce this functionality?

Edit:

I have read into the class [Certificate](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/Certificate.html) It looks like I might be able to user public/private keys to confirm an identity. But I am still unsure of an implementation

Comment: username/password in a keystore? If I understand you correctly, you want to restrict your webservice to apks signed by you?

Comment: That is correct, right now the only method I could imagine would be to confirm that the apk was digitally signed by me with my username/pass.

Comment: You sign with an username? How?

Comment: During the publishing process, you create a keystore file that includes your username/pass. It's what the Play Store uses to verify your identity. See more at http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this --

```
    static public String getPackageFingerPrint( Context ctx ) {
        PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
        String packageName = ctx.getPackageName();
        int flags = PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES;

        PackageInfo packageInfo = null;

        try {
                packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, flags);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                return "";
        }
        Signature[] signatures = packageInfo.signatures;

        byte[] cert = signatures[0].toByteArray();

        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(cert);

        CertificateFactory cf = null;
        try {
                cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");


        } catch (CertificateException e) {
                return "";
        }
        X509Certificate c = null;
        try {
                c = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(input);
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
                return "";
        }


        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
            byte[] publicKey = md.digest(c.getPublicKey().getEncoded());


            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i=0;i<publicKey.length;i++) {
                String appendString = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & publicKey[i]);
                if(appendString.length()==1)hexString.append("0");
                hexString.append(appendString);
                }


            return hexString.toString();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
            return "";
        } 
    }
```

The problem I see with your approach is that anyone could determine the package fingerprint or your package and send it to your web-service. A better possibility would be to use a challenge-response mechanism: Your web-service sends you a unique session-token, which your app encrypts or digests using a shared algorithm, and then sends this encrypted token back to your service for verification. Of course, you wouldn't want to publish that algorithm to github.

Comment: This method looks really helpful. However for what you offer about having a shared algorithm - i'm hesitant to put any "secret" in the apk since it is so trivial to decompile and find out how almost any section of the app is coded

Comment: That's true, of course -- you can obfuscate your code a bit, but in the end, there's no such thing as secure java. But even if you use the key or fingerprint, once it goes over the wire, it's fair game.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict a web service to apks signed by a specific key.

The signature of your apk gets validated by the Android OS, and is not directly shared with web services the device connects to. Even if you read your signature from the keystore and send it along with requests, an attacker could just send the same signature (e.g. the same byte stream) without having access to your private key. He would just need to grab your signed apk, read the bytes from the keystore (or listen to a legitimate request) and spoil the data.

You would need to sign individual requests to have a level of security. But if you keep a private key in release versions (the key not distributed on gitHub), and sign requests using that key you are not safe as the private key is distributed as part of your apk and thus can get extracted easily.

In any way your API could get accessed by other apks.

However, there might be another way to restrict your API, for example by using license tokens, etc. In that case you would probably not care if the user builds the apk by himself, as long as he has a valid license token. If a license token is exploited and distributed, you could react to a high amount of traffic on that license token and for example block it from further requests. As I don't use Google Play I'm not sure in how far they can get validated from your server, but maybe the [application licensing portal](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) is a good starting point to search for suitable tokens.